# How to get id in other route vuejs, vuerouter

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Here i can get id of company by @click event whenever i choose company, It's get id accord company.

And now i want my Sidebar(navbar) get id accord url corresponding whenever i @click option in sidebar(product,sale,...) it gonna be :"companies/48/products" for example

```
{

    path: "",

    name: "Company",

    component: () =>

      import ("../views/DashboardLayout.vue"),

    meta: { requiresAuth: true },

    props: true,

    children: [{

        path: "companies",

        component: () =>

          import ("../views/CompaniesLayout.vue"),

        children: [{

            path: "",

            component: () =>

              import ("../companies/views/CompaniesDashboard.vue"),

          },

          {

            path: ":companyId/contacts",

            component: () =>

              import ("../views/Contacts.vue"),

          },

          {

            path: ":companyId/products",

            component: () =>

              import ("../views/Products.vue"),

          },

          {

            path: ":companyId/sales",

            component: () =>

              import ("../views/Sales.vue"),

          },

          {

            path: ":companyId/fees",

            component: () =>

              import ("../views/Fees.vue"),

          },

          {

            path: ":companyId/employees",

            component: () =>

              import ("../views/Employees.vue"),

          },

          {

            path: ":companyId/setting",

            component: () =>

              import ("../views/Setting.vue"),

          },

          {

            path: "create",

            component: () =>

              import ("../companies/views/RegisterCompany.vue"),

          },

        ],

      },

      {

        path: "/dashboard",

        component: () =>

          import ("../views/WelcomeDashboard.vue"),

      },

      {

        path: "/profile",

        component: () =>

          import ("../profile/views/Profile.vue"),

      },

      {

        path: "products",

        component: () =>

          import ("../views/Products.vue"),

      },

      {

        path: "sales",

        component: () =>

          import ("../views/Sales.vue"),

      },

      {

        path: "fees",

        component: () =>

          import ("../views/Fees.vue"),

      },

      {

        path: "employees",

        component: () =>

          import ("../views/Employees.vue"),

      },

      {

        path: "setting",

        component: () =>

       `   import ("../views/Setting.vue"),`

      },

    ],

  },

];
```

Here my route

links: [

```
  {

    to: "/dashboard",

    icon: "mdi-view-dashboard",

    text: "Dashboard",

  },

  {

    to: `/companies/1/sales`,

    icon: "mdi-currency-usd",

    text: "Sales",

  },

  {

    to: `/companies/1/contacts`,

    icon: "mdi-domain",

    text: "Contacts",

  },

  {

    to: `/companies/1/products`,

    icon: "mdi-cube-outline",

    text: "Products",

  },

  {

    to: `/companies/1/fees`,

    icon: "mdi-calculator-variant-outline",

    text: "Fees",

  },

  {

    to: `/companies/1/employees`,

    icon: "mdi-account-supervisor",

    text: "Employees",

  },

  {

    to: `/companies/1/setting`,

    icon: "mdi-cog",

    text: "Company setting",

  },

],
```

Here my data link. I set hard id = 1 to sure it right. it's supposed to `companies/${companyId}/setting` for example. If you want any code to compare, tell me.
Tks everyone so much..
Bonus loom for everyone know my issue
https://www.loom.com/share/32228acb3d6e4e77b496f9791d730879

Comment: If your project is in GitHub and isn't overly large or complicated, I suggest importing it into CodeSandbox to make it easier for others to analyze.

Comment: tks for your feedback

Comment: Check this out https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode